# how to rotate a "characterController" third person character

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a capsule Gameobject as my Character and moving it using CharacterController.Move();
everything was working good till I tried to rotate the character

I used Transform.rotate(); to rotate my character and it is rotating it correctly as I want

I noticed that when I rotate my character its CharacterController "Collider" does not rotate with the character... and that is making my move looks weird since when I try to move forward after I rotate my characters to the right
it moves to the left

Comment: Put the capsule object in a parent gameobject and do your rotations on the parent gameobject

Answer (score 0):

Try `CharacterController.Move(transform.rotation * yourVector)` to adjust for rotation.

Answer (score 0):

I used the nav mesh instead of it thank you and moves my character using the transform.position and everthing worked fine

thanks all